# Use phone connected to local machine to develop on remote desktop Android Studio

Tags: android, remote-desktop

I work on Windows Remote Desktop. Local and remote OS are Windows 10.
I need to access my android phone connected to my laptop via USB in Android Studio which is running on the remote desktop to build app directly on my phone.
My phone is visible in the Remote Desktop Connection configuration "Local devices and resources" list and is checked in, but adb doesn't see the device on the remote desktop. (Even the remote dekstop OS doesn't see it)

Comment: Is your device Android 11 or above?

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel Yes, it is an Xiaomi MI 9 with Android 11.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky but adb have the power to connect **any network-reachable device on the globe** with the correct configuration.

No need for USB, just connect device to the local WiFi.

The action involves port forwarding on your home router.
You need to do 2 things:

1. Pair device - only 1 time but the device will un-pair itself if not connected to adb for a while.
2. Connect device - each time you plug your device

Pairing instructions (Android 11 or above):

1. Extract your home network's external IP, let's call it `HOME_IP`.
2. Turn on wireless debugging from developer options.
3. In wireless debugging screen, choose to pair with code - the IP of your device and some port will show up (along with 6-digit code), let's name those `DEVICE_IP` and `PAIRING_PORT` respectively.
4. Add the following port forwarding rule to your router: protocol TCP, external & internal ports `PAIRING_PORT`, ip `DEVICE_IP`.
5. In the remote OS, execute (without <> chars) `adb pair <HOME_IP>:<PAIRING_PORT>`, then enter the 6-digits code from device.

**Note that step 3 is with timeout so prepare your router settings screen and remote OS's cmd before step 3.**

Connecting instructions:

1. After successful pairing, in wireless debugging screen, an ip and port will show up, let's call those `DEVICE_IP` and `CONNECTION_PORT` respectively.
2. Add the following port forwarding rule to your router: protocol TCP, external & internal ports `CONNECTION_PORT`, ip `DEVICE_IP`.
3. In the remote OS, execute (without <> chars) `adb connect <HOME_IP>:<CONNECTION_PORT>`.

Assuming the remote desktop is at your office - make sure your requests passes corporate firewall.

Comment: I've got "Failed: Unable to start pairing client."

Comment: Sounds like a firewall - check with the security folks if they can make an exception. This method is working and being tested on a daily basis.